# How do I know whether a community user is the first time using the Community_URL?

Tags: email-template, customer-portal, customer-community, community, urlhacking

This is related to Customer Community. Once the customer user is enabled by the System Admin, the User will receive the Welcome Email. In the Email, it contains `{!Community_url}`. If the User clicks that link, he/she will be redirected to reset password page to set up their new password.

However, this reset password page is all the same no matter the User is first time clicking the `{!Community_url}` or clicking the link sent with the Email when "forgot password" happens. Here our team want to show different contents on that page for different occasions. Then, how do we identify whether this user is clicking that link via Welcome Email or Forgot Password Email? Is it possible to do it in the Controller?

Thanks for anyone with any helpful thought.